# Cannot override inherited member SelectTemplate... with code I copied from MSDN

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I have an override problem.  I know you can't override inherited members unless they are marked virtual, abstract or override, but...

I have  [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) from msdn:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SDKSample
{
    public class TaskListDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate
            SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

            if (element != null && item != null && item is Task)
            {
                Task taskitem = item as Task;

                if (taskitem.Priority == 1)
                    return
                        element.FindResource("importantTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                else 
                    return
                        element.FindResource("myTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And I added this code:

```
public class PostTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = item as ListViewItem;

        AppNetClient.PostClass key = lvi.DataContext as AppNetClient.PostClass;

        if (key.postTemplate == "Post")
        {
            return lvi.FindName("PostDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return lvi.FindName("SelectedPostDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Error   3   'oneSocialLife.MainPage.PostTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(object, Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject)': cannot override inherited member 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(object, Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject)' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override   C:\Users\kcone\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\HttpClientApp\HttpClientApp\MainPage.xaml.cs   339 42  oneSocialLife
```

I've spent hours looking for why, but can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sample you're referencing is for WPF ([System.Windows.Controls.DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)).

In a Windows Store app, you're using [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209469.aspx) which has different semantics, and [SelectTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.selecttemplate.aspx) is indeed not overridable, but [SelectTemplateCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector.selecttemplatecore.aspx) is.

Comment: So I had to make two changes: from "public override ... SelectTemplate" to "protected override SelectTemplateCore"  Then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

The code that ended up working:
    from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx
    also: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

```
public class PostTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate PostTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SelectedPostTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        //ListViewItem lvi = item as ListViewItem;
        //AppNetClient.PostClass key = lvi.DataContext as AppNetClient.PostClass;

        AppNetClient.PostClass key = item as AppNetClient.PostClass;

        if (key.postTemplate == "Post")
        {
            return PostTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return SelectedPostTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```